# Gompertz distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to prove that the Gompertz distribution function is indeed of distribution, I'm certain this function would never be negative, the problem comes when integrating the function with parameters: $b,\eta > 0$

$$f(x)  = \begin{cases}
b\eta\;\exp(\eta+bx-\eta e^{bx})&\text{for $x\geq0$}\\
0&\text{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}$$

So far I have:
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} b\eta\;\exp(\eta+bx-\eta e^{bx})  \,dx  = 1$$

$$\Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty} b\eta\;\exp(\eta+bx-\eta e^{bx}) \,dx = b\eta\int_{0}^{\infty} \;\exp(\eta+bx-\eta e^{bx}) dx$$

I don't know how to treat the $exp$, can someone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the density as $$f(x) = e^\eta (b \eta e^{bx}) \exp(-\eta e^{bx}).$$  Then with the substitution $$u = \eta e^{bx}, \quad du = b \eta e^{bx} \, dx,$$ we see $$\int f(x) \, dx = e^\eta \int e^{-u} \, du.$$  I leave the rest of the computation as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Taking what was said

$$ \int e^{-u} du =  -e^{-u} $$

Substitute back in $u =\eta e^{bx}$

$$ - e^{\eta}\cdot e^{-\eta e^{bx}} \Big|_{0}^{\infty} $$

The negative will reverse it and we pull out $e^{\eta}$

$$ = e^{\eta} (e^{-\eta}  - \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} e^{-\eta e^{bx}}) $$

The second term will go to $0$ and we get

$$ e^{\eta} \cdot e^{-\eta} = 1$$